# Insert data with column families using MapReduce into HBase using Apache Phoenix

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm new to HBase and Phoenix. I've been trying to insert data into a HBase table in multiple column families using MapReduce using Apache Phoenix.

Here's is my HBase table created by Phoenix

```
CREATE TABLE defect (planning_folder_id varchar(12) NOT NULL, artifact_id VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL, data.category VARCHAR, data.root_cause VARCHAR, association.artifact_id VARCHAR(12) CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (planning_folder_id, artifact_id));
```

from the above Phoenix create table syntax, the table would look simply like the following

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| planning_folder_id | artifact_id | data:category | data:root_cause | association:artifact_id | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     plan1234        |   artf1234  |     cat_a      |      cause_a   |       artf2345
                                                                             artf5678
                                                                             artf8987
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     plan6765        |   artf5454  |     cat_b      |      cause_a   |       artf2222
                                                                             artf7643
                                                                             artf2345
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Right, as you can see, each artifact has a number of related artifacts identified by column family, association, and qualifier, artifact_id.

Back to my question, I want to write a mapreduce job that reads data and populate into the table I mentioned above.

Here's what I have

Mapper

```
public class PhoenixMapper<K> extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, K, DefectWritable> {

    private Parser parser = new MyParser();

    @Override
    protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String document = value.toString();
        try {
            Artifact artf = parser.parse(document);
            DefectWritable defect = new DefectWritable();
            defect.setPlanningFolderId(artf.getPlanningFolderId());
            defect.setArtifactId(artf.getId());
            defect.setRootCause(artf.getRootCause());
            defect.setCategory(artf.getCategory());


            // How to insert this into the hbase table
            defect.setAssociations(artf.getAssociations());

            context.write(null, defect);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Defect Writable (to be written into the table)

```
public class DefectWritable implements DBWritable {

    private String planningFolderId;
    private String artifactId;
    private String rootCause;
    private String category;
    private String[] associations;

    // getters/setters ignored

    @Override
    public void write(PreparedStatement pstmt) throws SQLException {
        pstmt.setString(1, planningFolderId);
        pstmt.setString(2, artifactId);
        pstmt.setString(3, category);
        pstmt.setString(4, rootCause);
        // what to do with "associations"?
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        planningFolderId = rs.getString("PLANNING_FOLDER_ID");
        artifactId = rs.getString("ARTIFACT_ID");
        category = rs.getString("CATEGORY");
        rootCause = rs.getString("ROOT_CAUSE");

    // what to do with association:artifact_id Array associationArray = rs.getArray("ASSOCIATION"); ?

    }
}
```

DataImporter

```
    public class PhoenixDataImporter extends Configured implements Tool {
    private static final String DOCUMENT_START_TAG = "<artifact>";
    private static final String DOCUMENT_END_TAG = "</artifact>";
    private static final String TABLE_DEFECT = "DEFECT"; 

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = getConf();
        conf.set("xmlinput.start", DOCUMENT_START_TAG);
        conf.set("xmlinput.end", DOCUMENT_END_TAG);

        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, getClass().getSimpleName());
        job.setJarByClass(getClass());
        job.setInputFormatClass(XMLInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(PhoenixOutputFormat.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(DefectWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        job.setMapperClass(PhoenixMapper.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
        PhoenixMapReduceUtil.setOutput(job, TABLE_DEFECT, "PLANNING_FOLDER_ID,ARTIFACT_ID,CATEGORY,ROOT_CAUSE");
        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(HBaseConfiguration.create(), new PhoenixDataImporter(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }
}
```

The code currently inserts data into PLANNING_FOLDER_ID, ARTIFACT_ID, CATEGORY, ROOT_CAUSE columns. I have no idea how to insert into ASSOCIATION:ARTIFACT_ID because there could be multiple related artifacts for some artifacts. My current solution is based on https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_mr.html.

Can anyone help me with this? and since i'm new to hbase, maybe you guys could comment on my current table design? I thought of separating tables (another table for association:artifact_id) and join them when querying. However, I would incur the performance.

If there are unclear points you wish me to clarify, please comment below :)

thanks in advance

Peeranat

Comment: artifact_id is an array?

https://phoenix.apache.org/language/datatypes.html#array